# Android Studio "cmd+shift+f" shortcut on MacBook is opening Recent Files and Usages (Glitchy)

Tags: macos, android-studio, keyboard-shortcuts

While searching using Cmd+Shift+f shorcut to search usages in Android Studio, it opening for both Android Studio Usager and Recent files in Mac

[Recent File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XDG9v.jpg)
[Android Studio file usages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WWnbZ.png)
Because of this I need to cancel the Recent files in Mac and everytime I need to comeback to Android Studio.

It should only open Android Studio Name usages while I am using Android Studio.

Comment: This does not sound like a programming question. Have you checked the macos preferences to see whether you can disable the global shortcut?

Comment: Same problem here, in the system preference you cannot disable the shortcut...

Comment: I had the same issue from night to day.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep the Android Studio shortcut as it is, you can disable the macOS shortcut by going to **System Preferences** > **Keyboard** > **Shortcuts** > **Services** and disable **Searching** > **Spotlight** as shown in the picture:

[image: Settings.app]

Comment: This works great. CMD+Shift+F is no longer intercepted by Finder when I am in Android Studio, woohoo!

Comment: Also in case anyone is concerned, this does not disable Spotlight Search, and you can even still use CMD+Shift+F to open Recent Files in a search on your desktop. It simply makes it so this shortcut is no longer available when in other apps like Android Studio.

Answer (score -1):

"Finally, I could find the solution to this, it worked."

**Problem** -> Shortcut CMD+SHIFT+F was coinciding with MacOS Shortcut and Android Studio Shortcut.

**Solution** -> Change the Android Studio Shortcut for Find in Files.

**Steps:**

**Step 1-**
In Android Studio Move to **File** -> **Settings** -> **Keymap** and **change Keymaps** and Search for "Find in Files" Shortcut.[image]

**Step 2-**
Change the shortcut from CMD+SHIFT+F to other shortcut which is not coinciding with the MacOS shortcut. (Here I have changed to CMD+SHIFT+W as it was not coinciding with the system Shorcut)[image]

**Step 3-**
Remove the older shorcut from "Find in Files" by right clicking on that Keymap
[image]

Comment: this happens only with cmd + shift + f.

with all the other Finder shortcut shared also with Android Studio that issue is not happening.
And actually I don't want to change these shortcut in Android Studio. That is so annoyng.
I keep looking for a solution.